# Why $f(E\cap F)$ is a subset of $f(E)\cap f(F)$ and not equal to, example to prove?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if someone could provide an example of the following two set function relations. I understand the formal proof but cant see to construct an actual real life function that conforms to what is being proved.

1. $f(E\cup F) = f(E) \cup f(F)$ instead of this $f(E\cup F) \subseteq f(E) \cup f(F)$
   basically why equality holds but not subset.
2. $f(E\cap F) \subseteq f(E)\cap f(F)$ instead of $f(E\cap F) = f(E)\cap f(F)$
   why subset hold and equality only holds if bijection. The fact its a subset and not equality indicates its possible for the set $f(E)\cap f(F)$ to contain elements not contained in the set $f(E\cap F)$, but this counter intuitive since these are mappings so the domain should map to the range?

I cant seem to construct a function to verify the above. Unless the range contains values not mapped by the function domain which does not make sense.

any examples would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: sorry, this is my first time posting. I have corrected it. Thanks for the correction

Comment: For 2, take a constant function and $E,F$ disjoint and non-empty.

Comment: For 2., could you give an example in which $E\cap F=\emptyset$ but $f(E)\cap f(F) \neq \emptyset$. What would that involve?

Comment: For 1. we have that _both_ equality and subset holds. But the fact that equality holds makes subset entirely redundant.

Comment: $f(E\cup F)=f(E)\cup f(F)$ always holds: Clearly $f(E),f(F)\subset f(E\cup F)$; hence $f(E)\cup f(F)\subset f(E\cup F)$. In the other direction $y\in f(E\cup F)$ implies that $y=f(x$ for some $x\in E\cup F$. Then either $y\in f(E)$ or $y\in f(F)$, i.e., $f(E\cup F)\subset f(E)\cup f(F)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the second case, consider $g(x) = x^{2}$, $E = [-1,0]$ and $F = [0,1]$.

Then $E\cap F = \{0\}$ and $g(E\cap F) = \{0\}$.

On the other hand, $g(E) = [0,1]$, $g(F) = [0,1]$ and $g(E)\cap g(F) = [0,1$].

Hence we conclude that $g(E\cap F)\subseteq g(E)\cap g(F)$, but $g(E)\cap g(F)\not\subseteq g(E\cap F)$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank You so much, cant believe I could not construct one.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is injective then the equality always holds, if $f$ is not injective you have $x\neq y$ with $f(x) =f(y)$ and then taking $E= \{x\}$ and $F = \{y\}$ we have $f(E\cap F) = f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$ whereas $f(E) \cap f(F) = \{f(x)\} \cap \{f(y)\} = \{f(x)\}$

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear it.